# Executable file size increment when upgraded from Visual studio 2019 to Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

We are upgrading Visual studio version from VS v16.11.8 to VS v17.4.4 with some updated commits of dependent libraries in code.

If I use VS v17.4.4 to build the app ,  size of .exe file  has increased by 4.2 MB.

If I use VS v16.11.8 to build same code, there is only 0.1 Mb increment in size of .exe file.

Is the size of executable file dependent on compiler used?
Also is this  a known issue?
Any resolution to reduce the size?

I tried changing optimisation flag value in VS. but nothing working

Comment: Most probably it is a link to static crt as opposed to dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChourdakis for the response.
 This is the requirement to keep it statistically linked. This setting is present in existing Visual studio as well.
changing the link to dynamic is leading to error:
"mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'"